# Capacitor smoke: need to swap

Tags: capacitor

My capacitor is 560 μF, 250 V; I forgot the brand. I'm buying 560 μF, 450 V, is that OK or not?

I need some help; capacitor smoke because of an electric problem.

This capacitor is from a 3D printer. The printer is OK, but can't preheat.

Comment: The 450 volt capacitors will work fine.

Comment: what is the result of this? is that working as usual back to normal?

Comment: They will work as a replacement. You may still have other problems that caused them to fail

Comment: what do you mean to fail? like what or something?

Comment: "capacitor smoke coz of the electric problem," If the "electric problem" caused the capacitor to smoke then other components may be defective as well.

Comment: but the unit is ok, i check the board only capacitor got smoke the paper got pop.up, but when i preheat the unit when it comes to 50 temp the unit automatic reset, every time  the temp goes to 50 always reset

Comment: If the original caps had a safety rating, your new caps need to have same or better safery rating or you will make the power supply dangerous.

Comment: how to the check the rating of the capacitor?

Comment: What was the "electric problem"? Is the automatic reset at 50 the desired behavior, or is that the problem you hope the replacement capacitors will fix? Need more details.